# how does the "for each in" loop work?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, loops, for-loop

for some reason this code does not work as intended, I've cut out most of my program but, all I think I need to tell you is that I have a tree array, and I am trying to make collisions with said trees so I thought that this would work:

```
function collisions(loopEvent:Event):void
{
    for each (var a:tree in TreeArray)
    {
        if (brettMc.right1.hitTestObject(a.stump))
        {
            rightcoll = false;
        }
        else
        {
            rightcoll = true;
        }

        if (brettMc.left1.hitTestObject(a.stump))
        {
            leftcoll = false;
        }
        else
        {
            leftcoll = true;
        }

        if (brettMc.up1.hitTestObject(a.stump))
        {
            upcoll = false;
        }
        else
        {
            upcoll = true;
        }

        if (brettMc.down1.hitTestObject(a.stump))
        {
            downcoll = false;
        }
        else
        {
            downcoll = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I am pretty sure that the problem is just that the `for each loop` is messed up.

Comment: What is the intended result? What result do you get instead? The `for each loop` loop does what it does. It is not messed up. It's more likely that your expectation of what's going on is wrong. Please elaborate on how your code works and how you draw your conclusions.

Comment: @null okay, so let me know if you wanna see my entire code, but basically, i have a symbal, the as linkage is tree, i have two other for loops, one of them spawns in a set amount of trees, and the other one makes them keep on tele-porting around until they are not touching one and other.
i have basic movement on another symbal setup(arrow keys) it goes like 
if(left key && leftcoll) {
brett.x =-10
}
let me know if you need anymore info

Comment: @null just to be clear, there are multiple trees, but this code only seems to be affecting one of them

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issue with loop itself

EXCEPT

Is `TreeArray` actual name of variable? Or it's a Type?

If that's actual variable, can you trace the length of it before loop?

Comment: what do you mean by type, sorry i just started coding, so im kinda stupid. im pretty sure that treearray is a variable, it is an array that holds 4 trees.

Comment: this comment is just to notify you

Comment: Sorry, was away. So by convention we do name stuff in flash like:
`var variable : Type`. Variables using small letters and types with Capital first letter. That's why at first it looks like`TreeArray` is not a variable but type. Anyway, I don't think is your problem. Trace rightcoll,leftcoll,upcoll,downcoll values after every loop iteration to check them, but again - I think problem is somewhere else.

Comment: i think the problem is the else parts, because i feel like the first tree is saying that you are touching me so it sets the rightcoll to false (for example) then the second tree says that you are not touching me and sets it to true, therefore nullifying what the first tree says. or it could just be that i am dumb because i am

sorry for the stupid terminology

Comment: wait, ir ecall reading somewhere that you could use a line of code to end the function, would adding this to all of the collision: false lines fix things?

Comment: okay that works find, just adding a break line after ever complete seems to work, the problem is, and i have no idea why this is happening but sometimes the tree just ignores the command like before, this happens about 10% of attempts that i try to walk through the tree

Comment: sorry that im bothering you again, but an update on the last post, it seems that this error only happens for up/down collisions, and this happens to it every time, it doesent happen to left/right.
also, i was wondering if you can have one object in more than one array?

Comment: okay, im posetive that i am annoying you, but at the start of the loop when it says 
   for each (var a:tree in TreeArray)
and i wanted to make a seperate arrray, for all objects called CollArray
would i change it to
   for each (var a:tree in CollArray)
but then the problem is the whole tree thing, since it will have more than one type of object, thanks.

Comment: Whoa, that's quite a lot of comments. I think it's getting out of hand now : > Yes, you can have one object in more than one array. Anyway I'm pretty sure, whatever you're doing atm it can be done in different way. Is your main problem this one?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30546981/preventing-object-from-overlapping-on-top-of-each-other

Comment: no, i can hapily say that i solved that problem, i just needed to add in
if (a==b)
{
}
else{
then put all my code
}